# Replacing URLs in mutliple PDFs

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I just wanted to know if it was at all possible, via Acrobat's built-in Action Wizard or otherwise, to replace the underlying URL of some textual links in multiple PDFs?

Comment: Are all those links identical? What do you mean by "underlying URL"? Do you mean all links share the same domain (or some deeper path elements) and have different targets? Or are all links random and you want to replace them via some table or by manual dialog?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.